# If banished token then try to resummon it, possible?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I have a token on the field, then I used [Interdimensional Matter Transporter](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Interdimensional_Matter_Transporter), will it return to the field?

[Interdimensional Matter Transporter](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Interdimensional_Matter_Transporter):

> Target 1 face-up monster you control; banish that target until the End
>   Phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token won't return to the field, as as soon as the token leaves the field it is removed from the game entirely.

From the rulebook:

> Monster Tokens are monsters that appear on the field as the result of a card’s effect. They are not included in the Deck, *and **cannot** be sent anywhere other than the field*